# Is it possible to set the HttpMethod with MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock

Tags: static-resources

I utilize a rest API from our vendor that has the same endpoint but utilizes different Httpmethods (get,put,post,delete). Is it possible to set the HttpMethod when setting up the endpoint as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You'll want to use the HttpCalloutMock class instead, in order to be able to determine the correct response to send back to your code. I personally use a class that looks like the following:

```
public class EchoResponseCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    public HttpResponse[] responses = new HttpResponse[0];
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request) {
        return responses.remove(0);
    }
}
```

This allows me to craft many responses, and place them in order, and each one will be popped off the front of the list, in order, as calls are made. This also allows me to *not care* what the request looks like, simply because my unit tests are designed to force a certain code path to execute, so the responses should match the requests.

If that's really not your thing, then you'd have to use a complicated setup involving great swaths of if-then-else statements, or, since they all use the same endpoint, you might write a class like this:

```
public class MultiResponseCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
    Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> responses = new Map<String, HttpCalloutMock> {
        'get' => new GetCalloutMock(),
        'put' => new PutCalloutMock(),
        'delete' => new DeleteCalloutMock(),
        'patch' => new PatchCalloutMock(),
        'post' => new PostCalloutMock()
    };
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request) {
        return responses.get(request.getMethod().toLowerCase()).respond(request);
    }
}

public class GetCalloutResponse implements HttpCalloutMock {
    public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest request) {
        // do something specific here
    }
}

public class PutCalloutResponse implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // You get the idea
// ...
```

If you want to use the MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock, you'd have to constantly reconfigure it anyways, so there's not much bonus there. For example, all responses have the same status code (e.g. 200), so if you need some 3xx, 4xx, or 5xx codes intermingled, you'll have to use multiple calls to the utility class.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox, I think keeping it simple will be the best course of action here. I do know the order of the calls and what is to be returned so I like your first suggestion.